# Qt Creator - How to deploy application using static parameter

Tags: qt, deployment, qml, static-libraries, static-linking

I am trying on windows deploy and application as static, so the single exe file will include all required dlls inside.
So when I distribute this single exe file amoung PCs, it will be working fine.

At the moment, when I release the project via windeployqt (including QMLs), it bring whole bunch of dlls and qmls in the folder. So I need to join it together (sometling like ILMerge software does) using QT.

Please guide me through the process.

PS: Compiler is MinGW 32b

Thanks

Comment: First link from Google - [Creating standalone application](https://wiki.qt.io/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows)

Comment: @folibis I have tried that of course, but it did not work (no error, just usual build)

Comment: So, you did that wrong. Btw, you need comercial licence for the static build.

Comment: @folibis Actually no. You need to distribute the Qt libraries according to LQPL and allow user to modify and change them, if you choose LGPL license. But you can still give out only the compiled object code for your own code, and provide instructions on how to re-link the program using Qt libraries of user's choice. It's a lot of hassle, but it is possible. Still, valid point to OP, you need to follow the LGPL even with static binary!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking options mentioned, I have found visualized [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwX_urJJOf8),
Which is quite easy way, however time consuming...

only one point for future googliers, DON'T FORTGET to fix the sqlite parameter, otherwise 7 hours long process will get stuck in the middle, and you will have to start over again as me :)

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not offer static build downloads. You would need to build Qt yourself. There are instructions to get you started:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html

However, an easier alternative is MXE, which will build a static Qt for you:

https://mxe.cc

To speed up building Qt in MXE, you should add:

```
JOBS := 4
```

in `settings.mk` (replace "4" with the amount of CPU cores in your system.) To only build static libraries (which is what you want), change `MXE_TARGETS` to:

```
MXE_TARGETS := i686-w64-mingw32.static
```

`settings.mk` does not exist initially. Run:

```
make check-requirements
```

to create it.

You should follow the instructions on https://mxe.cc carefully. If everything seems file, you then do:

```
make qtbase
```

to build the toolchain. This will build GCC, all libraries required by Qt and then Qt itself. Initial setup takes a while since it needs to build everything.

MXE requires Linux, macOS or the Linux Subsystem for Windows. I recommend Linux. Using MXE, you would develop your application normally with the official Qt, but when you want to build a release of your app, you would build it using the MXE toolchain, which provides a static version of Qt.

Qt is only one library provided by MXE. It provides static builds of many other libraries as well.